If broken image redirect
I have this problem. How to edit this code to redirect to custom url instead of removing broken images?
The below code is builded to remove broken images on wordpress. I want to change the function to redirect.
There are 3 files:

1. remove-broken-images.php

##########################################


 // Don't load directly
    if (!defined('ABSPATH')) { exit; }
    
    // Enqueue script
    function r34rbi_enqueue_script() {
        wp_enqueue_script('r34rbi', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'assets/script.min.js', array('jquery'), '1.2.0', true);
    }
    add_action('init', 'r34rbi_enqueue_script');

##########################################

2.script.js

function r34rbi(elem) {

    // Identify parent 'a' and ancestor '.wp-caption' elements
    var ancestor_caption = elem.closest('.wp-caption');
    var parent_link = elem.parent('a');

    // If ancestor caption exists, remove it entirely
    if (ancestor_caption.length > 0) { ancestor_caption.remove(); }
    
    // If parent link exists, remove it entirely
    else if (parent_link.length > 0) { parent_link.remove(); }
    
    // Just remove the image
    else if (elem.length > 0) { elem.remove(); }

}

jQuery(function() {

    // Images in DOM on initial load
    jQuery('img').on('error', function() { r34rbi(jQuery(this)); });
    
    // Images inserted into DOM by AJAX
    jQuery(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
        jQuery('img').on('error', function() { r34rbi(jQuery(this)); });
    });

});

##########################################

3.script.min.js

function r34rbi(n){var r=n.closest(".wp-caption"),e=n.parent("a");r.length>0?r.remove():e.length>0?e.remove():n.length>0&&n.remove()}jQuery(function(){jQuery("img").on("error",function(){r34rbi(jQuery(this))}),jQuery(document).ajaxComplete(function(){jQuery("img").on("error",function(){r34rbi(jQuery(this))})})}); 

